# pythonでキーボードの入力を無効化したい

Tags: python, python3

プログラム初心者です。
キーボードの入力をpython以外で無効化したいです。
具体的には、キーボードを押すー＞pythonで入力を受け取るー＞他のソフトには出力されない
ということをしたいです。

調べてみたところ、pynputのmouse.Listenerで同じような事ができると知り、
一度試してみて、マウス側は期待通りの動きをしてくれたのですが、キーボードの方はうまくいきませんでした。
keyboardライブラリのblock_keyなども使ってみたのですが、うまく動きませんでした。

以下が思い通りに動作したマウス側のプログラムです。

```
from time import sleep
import ctypes
import threading
from pynput import mouse
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Key

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    global mousel,mouser,mousex1,mousex2
    buttons = str(button).replace("'", '')
    if buttons=="Button.left":
       if pressed:
         mousel=True 
         print("pressLeft")
       else:
         mousel=False
         print("releaseLeft")
       Mouselistener.suppress_event()
    if buttons=="Button.right":
       if pressed:
         mouser=True
         print("pressright")
       else:
         mouser=False
         print("releaseright")
       Mouselistener.suppress_event()
    if buttons=="Button.x2":
       if pressed:
         mousex2=True
       else:
         mousex2=False

Mouselistener = mouse.Listener(
    on_click  = on_click,
    suppress  = False
)

Mouselistener.start()
```

そして、うまく動作しなかったのがこれです。

```
from time import sleep
import ctypes
import threading
from pynput import mouse
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Key

def on_press(key):
      print('called')
      keys =str(key).replace("'", '')
      print(keys)
      if keys=="w":
         keyW=True
         print("pressed W")
      Keyboardlistener.suppress_event()

def on_release(key):
      keys =str(key).replace("'", '')
      if keys=="w":
         keyW=False
         print("released W")
      Keyboardlistener.suppress_event()

Keyboardlistener = keyboard.Listener(
    on_press   = on_press,
    on_release = on_release,
    suppress  = False
)

Keyboardlistener.start()
```

マウス側と同じように入力を受け取ったあとに

```
keyboardlistener.suppress_event()
```

で入力を無効にしたかったのですが、
これをつけると

```
called
w        
pressed W
```

といったようにon_release()が実行されず、
またもう一度押してもon_press()が実行されません。

pythonに詳しい方、何か方法やコードの修正、またライブラリなどがあれば、教えてもらいたいです。
stackoverflowも初めて使うので、見にくかったりしたら申し訳ないです。